# Read images from Excel sheet row by row

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have stuck up in reading images from an Excel sheet.

I have one Excel sheet which includes employee information like name, address and photo of an employee. I want to read it using Java and store it into some user management system.

Following is my code:

```
int idColumn = ...;
POIFSFileSystem poifs = ...;
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(poifs);
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

List<HSSFPictureData> pictures = workbook.getAllPictures();
for (int i = 0; i < pictures.size(); i++) {
    HSSFPictureData picture = pictures.get(i);

    // This does not map to the row from the picture:
    HSSFRowrow = sheet.getRow(i);

    HSSFCell idCell = row.getCell(idColumn);
    long employeeId = idCell != null ? (long) idCell.getNumericCellValue() : 0;

    myUserService.updatePortrait(employeeId, picture.getData());
}
```

The problem is it's not mapping to the exact user as on Excel sheet: 
Suppose user *A* has image *A* on excel sheet. But it's not mapping to the user *A*. So I would like to know the read images row wise.

Comment: It would be great if you just provide the relevant section of the code and exact problem?

Comment: right now the problem is its not mapping to the exact user as on excel sheet. means suppose User 'A' has image 'Image A' on excel sheet . but its not mapping to the User 'A' . so i want to read images row wise . it will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 3):

As you might have noticed: a cell in Excel does never *contain* a `Picture` (or any other `Shape`). Instead there is a separate layer that contains all `Shape` objects for a sheet. Thats why you can place an image across multiple cells.

But you could use the *anchor* of a shape to determine to which cell it was attached during positioning:

```
int idColumn = ...;
int pictureColumn = ...;
HSSFSheet sheet = ...;

for (HSSFShape shape : sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getChildren()) {
    if (shape instanceof HSSFPicture) {
        HSSFPicture picture = (HSSFPicture) shape;
        HSSFClientAnchor anchor = (HSSFClientAnchor) picture.getAnchor();

        // Ensure to use only relevant pictures
        if (anchor.getCol1() == pictureColumn) {

            // Use the row from the anchor
            HSSFRow pictureRow = sheet.getRow(anchor.getRow1());
            if (pictureRow != null) {
                HSSFCell idCell = pictureRow.getCell(idColumn);
                if (idCell != null) {
                    long employeeId = (long) idCell.getNumericCellValue();
                    myUserService.updatePortrait(employeeId, picture.getData());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the `HSSFPatriarch` in my example, as this makes it possible to determine the pictures *per sheet* (if you've got more than one sheet in the file).

It's important to notice that the anchor of a shape doesn't need to be in the cell where the picture is visually positioned - although usually it is. In that case you could extract the position from the `dx1` and `dy1` attributes of the anchor.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code to read images from an Excel sheet row by row:

```
POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis) ;
          HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(poifs);
          HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
          int idColumn1 = 14;
          int idColumn2 = 16;
          int pictureColumn = 0;
          //HSSFSheet sheet = null;

          for (HSSFShape shape : sheet.getDrawingPatriarch().getChildren()) {
              if (shape instanceof HSSFPicture) {
                  HSSFPicture picture = (HSSFPicture) shape;
                  HSSFClientAnchor anchor = (HSSFClientAnchor) picture.getAnchor();

                  // Ensure to use only relevant pictures
                  if (anchor.getCol1() == pictureColumn) {

                      // Use the row from the anchor
                      HSSFRow pictureRow = sheet.getRow(anchor.getRow1());
                      if (pictureRow != null) {
                          HSSFCell idCell14 = pictureRow.getCell(17);
                          HSSFCell idCell16 = pictureRow.getCell(19);
                         System.out.println(idCell14);
                              int age  =  (int)idCell14.getNumericCellValue();
                              int year  =  (int)idCell16.getNumericCellValue();

                              System.out.println(age+":"+year);
                              HSSFPictureData data = picture.getPictureData();
                             byte data1[] = data.getData();
                         FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(age+"."+year+".png");
                              out.write(data1);
                              out.close();
                              pcount++;
                         }
                  }
              }
```

Comment: This is not an answer, but seems to be just a test of the code of my answer.