# How do I read excel file containing images using Apache POI?

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I checked most of the examples on stack overflow but all read excel file of string value, numeric value etc using Apache POI library .

> I want to read .xlsx and .xls file containing images using Apache POI. If anyone knows..
>    kindly help me or suggest any hint on how to do this.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795947/read-images-from-xls-file-together-with-the-references-for-their-locations

Comment: What did you try to extend the examples you found to cover images? What documentation did you try to follow to work with images? What didn't work?

Comment: @Gagravarr i tried various links but didn't found solution. e.g. the links like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658315/reading-images-and-data-from-excel-file-using-poi and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030908/read-images-from-excel-sheet-row-by-row

Comment: @AyushBansal Thanks.. but i tried this one also